# Cannot find reference to textbox's selectionstart, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to set the position of the cursor to the end of the textbox using the selectionstart, but it always shows an error that says I'm missing a reference, even though I have added this: using System.Windows.Controls;
and I added the assembly reference presentationframework.

What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to show the relevant code...the problem with just describing what you've done is that, in your understanding, you haven't done anything incorrectly. So when you describe the issue, you won't describe a problem (because you aren't seeing it). If you show the code, then you have more eyes on the actual implementation and someone may be able to help.

Comment: ASP.NET ??? System.Windows.Controls?